# Remote Debug Azure App Service in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm having trouble debugging my code on Azure App Services...it all "seems" like it should be working, but no breakpoints are hit, here's my setup.

1. C# MVC Website running using .NET 4.5.1 as a .NET Core Application (this is probably the most important detail)
2. Deploy a "debug" version to Azure App Services
3. Use the Azure portal to enable debugging for my version (remote debugging ON, Version 2015)
4. Use the "Cloud Explorer" in Visual Studio 2015 to "Attach Debugger" to the app service.

At this point, the Visual Studio interface will "attach", it'll go into debugger mode, I'll see a few output lines, but no modules for the site will load, and no breakpoints will ever be hit.

I've attempted to "attach" to other processes on that machine, but it's a shot in the dark without knowing exactly what I'm doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you are behind a firewall blocking the required ports?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's the case. The remote debugger finds the azure machine, connects, launches the browser...all the things that indicate it's working. I can even choose debug -> attach to process and choose the azure machines processes.